# Quota for calling links of autogenerated video thumbnalis

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I was looking a way to get and show thumbnails of youtube videos in a client side app. Finally I found this auto-generated links:

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/0.jpg
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/1.jpg
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/2.jpg
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/3.jpg
```

and this

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/maxresdefault.jpg
```

However I couldn't find any mention about the limit of calls. It is possible that, the app will get more that 5 million calls a month and wanted to know if it can be a problem for me to call that auto-generated links.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]; then do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic).

Comment: The YouTube Data API is not documenting the URLs you've shown above. Thus these URLs -- even if they actually work -- are outside the realm of the *official* YouTube Data API.